# Robolectric 2.2 issue with custom layout/view/font

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

am facing some problem with robolectric with android.
I need to run test case related to activity, which is inflated with a layout contains custom textview/button with custom fonts.

While running test case, it shows exception in inflating xml, 
java.lang.RuntimeException: error inflating layout ( sorry, not yet implemented).

Can you guys help me on solving this. 
Am using robolectric-2.2-20130726.010922-21-jar-with-dependencies.

Thanks in advance,

JRH

Comment: hi guys, any idea on this ? I am stuck with this issue.

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace? The layout inflater sorry exception is almost always masking the real issue. It might also help to post your layout xml.

Comment: Hi Corey, inflate issue is solved with 2.2 jar. But now am facing issue in this scenario.